# Cone splitting questions in Perelman's paper "Elements on Morse theory on Alexandrov spaces"

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I am reading Perelman's paper "Elements on Morse theory on Alexandrov spaces".
It is an important paper about the local structure of finite dimensional Alexandrov spaces. Perelman in this paper prove that Alexandrov space is a **MCS-space**, hence it has a conic structure locally.
But I find it hard to understand some of Perelman's comments in so called "MCS-space".

**Def**. A metrizable space $M_n$ is a **MCS-space** of dimension $n$ if, for each $x\in M_n$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and an compact MCS-space $M_{n-1}$ of dimension $n − 1$, such that there exists a homeomorphism from the cone of $M_{n-1}$ to $U$ such that it sends the cone point to $x$. Here, we regard the case of -1 dimension as the empty set and its cone as a single point.

Perelman remarked under this definition that

(a) Under the definition of MCS-space that the **$l$-dimensional stratum** consists of those points $x\in M_n$ whose conic  nbhd admits a topological splitting $\mathbb{R}^m\times C(M_{n-m-1})$ (here $C(M_{n-m-1})$ is a cone over an $n-1$ dimensional MCS-space) for all $m\leq l$.

(b) The $l$-dimensional stratum is an $l$-manifold.

First question, It seems that every point in a $n$-dim MCS-space has a neighborhood homeomorphic to  $\mathbb{R}^m\times C(M_{n-m-1})$ for some $m\leq n$. But I don't know why.

Second question, I can not understand that why $l$-dimensional stratum is an $l$-manifold. In fact,
$A_l=$($l$-dimensional stratum$)\setminus$(($l-1$)-dimensional stratum) is an $l$-manifold, since any point in $\mathbb{R}^l\times \{v\}$ is contained in $A_l$, where $v$ is the cone vertex of $C(M_{n-m-1})$. Am I wrong?

Can anyone helps me? Thanks!

Comment: best place to post this question is MO.

Comment: @Back2Basic I don't know whether it is too easy for the people in MO. If nobody answer my question here, I will post it to MO.

Comment: Since no one answer the questions, I posted it to MO.http://mathoverflow.net/questions/195497/

Comment: You can find the answer to your second question on the paragraph following Definition 185 on C.Plaut's survey Spaces of Curvature $\geq k$. If I may I have myself a question on this topic. It seems that using this stratification of Alexandrov spaces it is possible to prove that the set of singular points (that is, points whose space of directions is not homeomorphic to the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$) is of codimension at least 3. Do you know how to go about this proof? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: C. Plaut's survey is available here: 
http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/akp-papers/plaut-2.pdf

Comment: @Chu Thank you very much for your reference! For your question, I don't know why, whether $n\geq 3$? Since the singularities of the two dimensional polyhedral is two. Obviously, the singularities  are the vertices.

Comment: @Chu Since it is another question. Maybe you should ask it directly in other place.

Comment: @Zhang: The singularities that I mention are topological. In the example you propose, the vertices have tangent cone homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, so they are not topologically singular, unless I am failing to see something?